# What is the significance of i+1 in plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)?

Tags: matplotlib

What is the significance of i+1 in plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1) ? in the following code:

```
for i in range(9):
    plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    img = plt.imread(os.path.join(img_dir, random_images[i]))
    plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    plt.axis('off')
```

Comment: What do you mean significance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i+1` is the counter for the subplot in your 3x3 subplot grid.

**Why add 1?**

The subplot numbering starts from 1 but the `range(9)` starts from 0, so `i+1` is used here to add 9 subplots, starting from 1, 2, 3, ..., 8, 9

Answer (score 1):

matplotlib starts counting at 1, while the range function starts at 0.
range(9) will return 0...8, while matplotlib needs 1...9, the i+1 moves the range(9) results to numbers matplotlib expects